# Form hangs when called from DLL via PowerShell

Tags: forms, powershell, dll

I have a DLL file containing a few different classes. Inside this DLL i've created a Windows Form.

After building the DLL project, I opened up PowerShell (I used ISE for convenience..) and executed the below script -

```
[reflection.assembly]::LoadFile("...\MyDLL.dll")
$NewForm = New-Object (AssemblyName).(Class Name of a class with a few subs, one of which will show the form I created)
$NewForm.ShowForm()
```

ShowForm is a simple sub that shows the windows form by calling the forms name and .Show().

When I execute this, and the form appears, the form hangs. It's almost as if the entire form is disabled. I can't interact with any controls on the form, nor can I close it by pressing the red X at the top.

I'd like to store a few forms that go with methods I've created in DLL files, so that if I decide to use a form to go with them in other applications, I won't have to rebuild the form.

(To anyone who's wondering why, then, I'm using powershell - I feel it's easier to test out functions / subs in a DLL from Powershell first, since 3 lines in a commandline tool like Powershell can easily call a sub / function from a DLL instead of creating / modding / recompiling a .exe project to do the same)

Comment: Do you have message loop to handle form events?

Comment: I don't believe I do. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time I ever try to use a form object in PowerShell calling the .Show() method, it always seems to fail. You might consider trying .ShowDialog(), which blocks the current thread from doing anything until it exits, but the session doesn't hang. I haven't researched the "why" behind this yet, but for what you've described, I'm assuming .ShowDialog will work for you.